# how to use observable File variable in Getx controller

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management, gets, flutter-design

I am trying to use the observable File variable in Getx but it shows an error. and I don't know another option to make the File observable in getx.

Error

```
      [Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected. 
      You should only use GetX or Obx for the specific widget that will be updated.
      If you are seeing this error, you probably did not insert any observable variables into GetX/Obx 
      or insert them outside the scope that GetX considers suitable for an update 
      (example: GetX => HeavyWidget => variableObservable).
      If you need to update a parent widget and a child widget, wrap each one in an Obx/GetX.
```

getx controller code

```
   File? selectedCoverImage;


   Future pickeCoverImageFromGallery() async {
     final image = await ImagePicker()
         .pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 70);
     if (image == null) return;

       selectedCoverImage = File(image.path);
}
```

observable class

```
    Obx(
                    ()=> controller.selectedCoverImage != null
                          ? Image.file(
                              controller.selectedCoverImage!,
                              height: double.infinity,
                              width: double.infinity,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            )
                          : Image(
                              image: AssetImage(roomImage),
                              height: double.infinity,
                              width: double.infinity,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                    ),
```

if the file is selected then the selected file Otherwise shows the default set image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You Have to make the selectedCoverImage observable, you can use GetX's `Rx` classes. In your case, you can use `Rx<File>` to create an observable `selectedCoverImage`. Here's how you can modify your GetX controller code:

```
class YourController extends GetxController {

      Rx<File>? selectedCoverImage = Rx<File>(File(""));
    
      Future pickCoverImageFromGallery() async {
        final image = await ImagePicker()
            .pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 70);
        if (image == null) return;
    
        selectedCoverImage.value = File(image.path);
      }
    }
```

Now you can use Obx method:-

```
 Obx(
            () => controller.selectedCoverImage?.value != null
                ? Image.file(
                    controller.selectedCoverImage?.value??File(''),
                    height: double.infinity,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  )
                : Image(
                    image: AssetImage(roomImage),
                    height: double.infinity,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
          ),
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: this code did not run but I changed some lines and then ran it.

Comment: can you tell me what you changed? because this code working for me.

Comment: In My project, this code shows some file  errors, so I changed in the controller class "RxString selectedCoverImage = "".obs; "  , " selectedCoverImage.value = image!.path.toString();" , and Obs screen use " controller.selectedCoverImage.value != "" ",  an Image widget  "FileImage (File(controller.selectedCoverImage.value.toString()))" ,   but code is fine but my situation is different.